# Equivalent of arrow function in react is not working

Tags: reactjs

I have a component:

```
class ProbaShell extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    console.log('constructorStart');
    super(props);

this.state = {
    h:   5,
    w: 500
    };    
this.fadeIn1 = this.fadeIn1.bind(this);
}


fadeIn1() { 
        const interval = setInterval(function(){
            this.setState({ h: (this.state.h + 5) });
            if (this.state.h >= 400) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            } 
        },50);   
    }

fadeIn() {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({ h: (this.state.h + 5) });     
        if (this.state.h >= 400) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        } 
    }, 50);   
}

render(){
    console.log('render')
    return(
        <Proba style={{height: this.state.h}}/>
    )
}

componentDidMount(){
    console.log('compDidMount');
    this.fadeIn();
}
}
```

and it is working perfectly with function fadeIn but not with fadeIn1. I cannot work out why? I've read an article about using this but still do not get why?

Comment: Arrow functions inherent context, regular function blocks do not

Comment: If you pass an unbound function to `setInterval` you'll get the global window object as `this` context when the callback is executed. So `this.setState()` and `this.state` will fail.

Comment: @Aaron Is this 'this.fadeIn1 = this.fadeIn1.bind(this);' not enough to bind the function?

Comment: @Zet No, because that's just binding the outer function. The `setInterval` 
callback is still unbound, and will be executed in window object context.

Comment: @Aaron Is it possible to bind callback function in easy way?

Comment: @Zet Yes, use an arrow function or `function.bind(this)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the fat arrow `=>` it will auto bind it as a class method with the context. This does not happen for `function(){..}` so you have to bind it manually by doing

```
constructor(props){
    console.log('constructorStart');
    super(props);
    this.fadeIn1 = this.fadeIn1.bind(this);
}
```

and pass the context to the function e.g.

```
fadeIn1() {
    const interval = setInterval(function() {
        this.setState({
            h: (this.state.h + 5)
        });
        if (this.state.h >= 400) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }.bind(this), 50);
}
```

You can read more about [Handling Events in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) although this is more JavaScript specific.

Comment: This is not true. If you do var fadeIn = this.fadeIn1 and then call fadeIn, it won't work either

Comment: there is no auto binding. please look at the babel transform for such  case to see an example of how the lexical context is provided to arrow functions.

Comment: @Zet I updated my answer. Look at the `bind(this)` in setInterval

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because in javascript this is dynamic. `setInterval` is actually window.setInterval so inside the function, this will be window. arrow functions are more than syntaxic sugar, they actually do not redefine this.

Comment: I don't agree. You should be able to use `setInterval` without `window`.

Comment: mescorcalin: This is what I meant

`"use strict";
function foo(){
    console.log(this);

}

foo(); // undefined

window.setTimeout(foo, 50); // window

setTimeout(foo, 100); // window

setTimeout(function(){
   foo(); // undefined
}, 150);`

Comment: @mersocarlin You *can* use `setInterval` without `window` but that's because it just resolves the reference to global scope `window.setInterval` for you. Try `setInterval === window.setInterval`

Comment: @Axnyff I got you point. But this is not related to the actual question.

Comment: I agree, this is mostly irrelevant, I was just saying that this is not what you would expect because it is dynamic in javascript, the arrow function solve this

Comment: Correct. Not to mention that the only difference I see in his code is the use of  `function` in `fadeIn1` whereas `fadeIn` does not have it :)

Comment: It's not really irrelevant, OP's entire problem comes from the fact that `setInterval` callback is executing in `window` context. This is the only answer that kind of explains why.

Comment: The problem comes from the fact the callback is executing with a this which is not the React element, it would also fail with this === undefined

Comment: It couldn't in that case indeed. I said it is mostly irrelevant (maybe a bit exaggerated) because the whole problem comes from javascript having a dynamic this. A lot of people struggle when passing unbound function to child element, to me this is the same type of problem but I can understand how you'd be disagreeing